# Safari 8 Network Requests Empty

Tags: macos, menu, safari

I have a feeling that I may have toggled some settings, but I can't find it anymore.

Basically I am trying to monitor requests sent from my webapp. The usual method is Inspect Element → Timelines → Network Requests, where Safari gives me a graph of all the requests made.

Now I can see the graph, but I can't see the list of the requests made. Here's a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the area that you are interested in for it to be shown. At present, you have a blank area of the timeline selected, so no events are shown. Resize/move the timeline handles to show the relevant information in the timeline.

[image]